# How to make an assertion or verification of a import PDF modal is displayed?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify how to make a assertion or verification if this screen is displayed.

I do not have any idea of how to approach this do to this "modal" is not from the webpage, but from the browser.

It is possible to create a assertion of how this can be verified?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before your test you can get the current window count with following :

```
int windowCountBeforeTest = _driver.WindowHandles.Count;
```

After your dialog shows up you can check it with following :

```
Assert.True(windowCountBeforeTest < _driver.WindowHandles.Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot find a link which absolutely says so, the w3c webdriver specification does not appear to support interaction with browser based prompts and windows.

In windows this mean you cannot interact with basic authentication or download/upload window prompts from the browser. I am assuming this is true on Mac as well.

You will likely need a 3rd party library or tool to interact with it. Within IE11 on Windows I am forced to use [InputSimulatorCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulatorCore/) to interact and close download prompts from the browser as it does not support auto saving files. I have heard of others using AutoIT but I have never used it.